# change background color when selecting list view in android

Tags: android, listview, colors

I'm using 
drawable folder then ==>new xml ==>shape and using this code to change my list view style.

```
 <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
 <stroke android:color="#b7df18" android:width="2dp"/>
 <solid android:color="#53aee3"/>
```

row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner);

and it's works correctly **BUT** if I select a row the background of selected row doesn't change like a normal list view. ! what should i do ? how can i change that to my ideal color ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a list selector for changing background color when selecting. So first of all write a selector. One way to write a selector is like this, first create a xml file int the drawable folder like this, listselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/round_corner_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_corner"/>

</selector>
```

Then you can refer this selector to the list view,

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector"
```

Or do as you are doing,

```
row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listselector);
```

Comment: thanks i got it. but i want my list view style appears like thing that i wrote in round_corner.xml and when i click on that my selected background color row change to for example red.

Comment: I hope you understand my question .

Comment: OK, So you have to write your desired style drawable for selected state. e.g. write round_corner_selected.xml as you want for pressed state (like as you mentioned red bg). (do you wanted to know how to write that red_background?)

Comment: Yes. everything working correctly with  round_corner_selected.xml and I want to know how when I select a row background changing to e.g red

Answer (score 0):

In the `ListView` XML you can set a `listSelector` which is a separate drawable for when an item is selected.

Eg.

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```